# How can I access a native Java bitmap from Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, bitmap, native, native-code

I want to use a bitmap which is loaded in my native Java library in my Unity project.

**How can I pass a bitmap from Java to C#?**

Answer (score 0):

Due to your not very specific Question I just assume you have your image loaded as a `BufferedImage`. So here's a suggestion on how to do it:

Use the [JNA Library](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) to gain a better access to the resources of c#.

And then maybe do something similar to this:

```
BufferedImage someImage;
long somePointer;

DataBuffer data = someImage.getData().getDataBuffer();
int[] bankOffsets = data.getOffsets();
long offset = 0;
com.sun.jna.Pointer ptr = new com.sun.jna.Pointer(somePointer);
switch(data.getDataType()) {
case DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE: 
    byte[][] bbanks = ((DataBufferByte) data).getBankData();
    for (int i = 0; i < bbanks.length; i++, offset += bbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]) 
        ptr.write(offset, bbanks[i], bankOffsets[i], bbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]);
break;
case DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE:
    double[][] dbanks = ((DataBufferDouble) data).getBankData();
    for (int i = 0; i < dbanks.length; i++, offset += (dbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i])*8) 
        ptr.write(offset, dbanks[i], bankOffsets[i], dbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]);
break;
case DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT:
    float[][] fbanks = ((DataBufferFloat) data).getBankData();
    for (int i = 0; i < fbanks.length; i++, offset += (fbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i])*4) 
        ptr.write(offset, fbanks[i], bankOffsets[i], fbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]);
break;
case DataBuffer.TYPE_INT:
    int[][] ibanks = ((DataBufferInt) data).getBankData();
    for (int i = 0; i < ibanks.length; i++, offset += (ibanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i])*4) 
        ptr.write(offset, ibanks[i], bankOffsets[i], ibanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]);
break;
case DataBuffer.TYPE_SHORT:
    short[][] sbanks = ((DataBufferShort) data).getBankData();
    for (int i = 0; i < sbanks.length; i++, offset += (sbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i])*2) 
        ptr.write(offset, sbanks[i], bankOffsets[i], sbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]);
break;
case DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT:
    short[][] usbanks = ((DataBufferUShort) data).getBankData();
    for (int i = 0; i < usbanks.length; i++, offset += (usbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i])*2) 
        ptr.write(offset, usbanks[i], bankOffsets[i], usbanks[i].length - bankOffsets[i]);
break;
case DataBuffer.TYPE_UNDEFINED:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported data type");
}
```

The data written should be all your pixel color values. The format depends on the image type (can be obtained using the `getType()` method in the class `BufferedImage`.

Alternatively you could also use the Java Native Interface but I haven't looked into that.